# How to wrap n elements within another element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of `VideoGridItem` components which I want to render within a Grid. I am using `react-native-easy-grid` so I have `Grid`, `Row` and `Col` at my dispose.

There should be 2 `VideoGridItem`s per row so I want to wrap `Row` component around every 2.

How can I achieve this?

So effectively my markup would want to look like:

```
<Grid>
  <Row>
    <VideoGridItem /> { /* Renders a <Col> */ }
    <VideoGridItem />
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
 </Row>
</Grid>
```

Right now I have

```
<Grid>
    <VideoGridItem /> { /* Renders a <Col> */ }
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
    <VideoGridItem />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how many to render based upon an array...

```
const renderedRows = []
for (let i = 0; i < myVidItems.length; i += 2) {
  renderedRows.push(
    <Row>
      {Array(myVidItems[i + 1] ? 2 : 1).fill(<VideoGridItem />)}
    </Row>
  )
}

[...]

<Grid>
  {renderedRows}
</Grid>
```

I expect there's a better way tbh.

Comment: This solution works, but how would I pass video `props` into `<VideoGridItem />`. I have 48 items, if I try `{...videos[i]}`, I only get 24 items because of `i += 2`. Here's a JSFiddle of what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/pewgfeth/1/

Comment: In that case try changing it to: `{Array(myVidItems[i + 1] ? 2 : 1).fill(<VideoGridItem />).map((el, j) => <el {...videos[i + j]} />)}`

This answer is all without testing haha, let me know how it hoes.

Answer (score 0):

You have use native base its useful to customize the design

Refer the below link

http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.4.6/components#layout

or use {/n}

this is the use for brake the line

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should take a look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

flexbox makes it possible to show content based on your screen resolution. It is easy to use :-)